# Getting SocketTimeoutException after only four seconds?

Tags: google-app-engine

I'm opening a url and getting a SocketTimeoutException:

```
long now = System.currentTimeMillis();
try {
    URL url = new URL("https://example.com");
    InputStreamReader is = new InputStreamReader(url.openStream());
    ..
}
catch (SocketTimeoutException ex) {
    long diff = System.currentTimeMillis() - now;
    System.err.println("Timeout!: " + diff + "ms"); // ~4 seconds
}   

java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Timeout while fetching URL: https://example.com
    at com.google.appengine.api.urlfetch.URLFetchServiceImpl.convertApplicationException(URLFetchServiceImpl.java:142)
```

but the elapsed time is only 4 seconds. This code of mine hasn't changed since February, same with the "example.com" url it's hitting (which is also under my control).

Could something have changed at a lower level by the app engine team to reduce the length of time before a timeout exception is thrown?

Thanks

Comment: Is the URL reachable from AppEngine? Can you open it in a browser?

Comment: Yep, can open the url ok in a browser.